# importing PyQt4 modules

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4

I am not completely new to PyQt4, had it running before, but now (after update to Mac OSX.6) and reinstalling PyQt4 (4.9 with sip-4.13.1) every program that imports anything specific from PyQt4 quits with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloQt.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QLabel
ImportError: No module named QtGui
```

The strange thing is also that the Python.Framework contains static libraries for QtCore.a, but only a trivial `__init__.py` that does not specify what to load.

Thanks for suggestions
melli79

Comment: Can you import from within the interpreter?  Maybe that particular module was left out during installing.

Comment: try to import `PyQt4.QtGui` from within the interpreter gives the same problem.  The `QtGui` is the most important module (for me), because I want to create graphical user interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

which should work.